# Generating Random Number to autoincrement

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, increment

I have a number formate as follows 1500 and after an insert of a record, i want the number to go up to 1501.

here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE QuoteTable2
(
    QuoteID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
 , QNumber varchar(1500),

);
```

here is my trigger:

```
create TRIGGER tr_no ON quotetable2
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    BEGIN
      UPDATE QuoteTable2
      SET QNumber = inserted.QNumber +1
      FROM inserted 
      WHERE quotetable2.QuoteID = inserted.QuoteID;
    END
   GO
```

my results are always the same number as below:

```
QuoteID          QNumber
1                1501
1                1501
```

how can i modify the trigger to increment by 1 each time? in the example the quoteID and Qnumber are both the same - sorry for the formatting

Comment: QuoteID values *will* have gaps at some point. What about QNumber: do you expect no gaps or it to be the same as QuoteID?

Comment: figured it out !!

Answer (score 3):

You are updating the value from the inserted value, which is 1500, so it is always 1501.

You need to get the value from the source table `QuoteTable2` not from the `inserted`:

```
  UPDATE q
  SET q.QNumber = q.QNumber +1
  FROM QuoteTable2 as q 
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON q.QuoteID = i.QuoteID;
```

I suggest to declare that column as a `IDENTITY` column instead so that it will automatically be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the next code:

```
 ALTER TRIGGER tr_no ON quotetable2
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @COUNT INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM quotetable2)
      UPDATE QuoteTable2
      SET QNumber = inserted.QNumber + @COUNT -1
      FROM inserted 
      WHERE quotetable2.QuoteID = inserted.QuoteID;
    END
   GO
```

i count the rows on the table and use the value to get the increment, regards